# Extracting the value of a specific HTML element using XPath in Python

Tags: python, html, xpath, html-parsing, lxml

I have tried this

```
url = 'http://test.ir/'
content = s.get(url).content
tree = html.fromstring(content)
print [e.text_content() for e in tree.xpath('//div[@class="grouptext"]/text()[not(self:div)]')]
```

As you can see in the picture I want the *selected* part:
[image]

When I use

```
print [e.text_content() for e in tree.xpath('//div[@class="grouptext"]')]
```

The result shows me the selected part *and* the content of `<div class="grouptext">` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you just want the `text()` of the first occurence of the `<div>` tag you have to be more specific in your XPath expression. Either you tell the system that you explictly want the first one by adding `[1]`

```
print [e.text_content() for e in tree.xpath('//div[@class="grouptext"][1]')]
```

or you could select it by filtering for the `style` parameter:

```
print [e.text_content() for e in tree.xpath('//div[@class="grouptext" and @style]')]
```

You will have to decide which is the better way to go. This will depend on how the `<div>` tags show up in your XML in a more general case.